# The magic of STREAMS in Linux. When to finish?

Tags: c, linux, stream

Today at 5am I read an article about `read` system call. And things become significantly clear for me.

> ssize_t read(int fd, void *buf, size_t count);

The construction of `*nix` like operation system become  amazing in it's simplicity. File interface for any entity, just ask to write some date from this `fd` interface into some memory by `*buf` pointer. All the same for network, files, streams.

But some question appears. 
**How to distinguish two cases?: 
1) Stream is empty need to wait for new data. 2) Stream is closed need to close program.**

Here is a scenario:

- Reading data from `STDIN` in loop, this `STDIN` redirected by `pipe`.
- some `text_data` appears
- just read bite by bite until what `EOF` in memory, or `0` as result of `read` call?
- How program will understand: **wait for a new input, or exit?**

This is unclear. In case of `endless` or `continuous` streams.

**UPD** After speak with @Bailey Kocin and reading some docs I have this understanding.  Fix me if I'm wrong.

- `read` holds the program execution and waits for `count` amount of bites.
- When `count` amount of bites appears `read` writes it into `buf` and execution continues.
- When `stream` is closed `read` returns `0`, and it is a signal that program may be finished.

**Question** Do `EOF` appears in `buf`?

**UPD2** `EOF` is a constant that can be in the output of `getc` function

```
 while (ch != EOF)     { 
    /* display contents of file on screen */ 
    putchar(ch);  

    ch = getc(fp);   
 }
```

But in case of `read` the `EOF` value dose not appears in a `buf`. `read` system call signalize about file ending by returning `0`. Instead of writing `EOF` constant into the `data-area`, as like ak in case of `getc`.

`EOF` is a constant that vary in different systems. And it used for `getc`.

Comment: Each device communicates with the kernel through yet another layer of abstraction. If fd is not open then the syscall failed or the device cant communicate. If you read and nothing is there then maybe nothing is there. What are you asking here?

Comment: @BaileyKocin I'm interested in mechanism reading data line by line from a stream. How do program waits for a new input?  just `x = read(file,buf,count)` and it's all what in code printed.  System automatically return bite when it's appears?

Comment: A hard drive has a device driver that the kernel uses to communicate with the hardrive. The harddrive takes specific commands through its firmware. It usually just writes directly to memory if a dma is available. The kernel buffer will receive the bytes and then the user will receive them in thier buffer. Perhaps you should read an operating systems book??

Comment: @BaileyKocin you are going to deep into OS, and far away from my question. I'm asking mostly about `C` program behavior. What code, and how it will reflects.

Comment: read. Is a system call. You have to go into the OS to understand it. I think you misunderstanding how complicated the function is and what the kernel abstracts from you. If you really want an exact answer go to where read is defined and look at its implementation. Start looking in unistd.h

Comment: @BaileyKocin the purpose of `C` and other hight-level programing languages is to hide an complication in to simple abstraction. And I asked how do `C` program distinct two situations (wait/time to exit). Reading your messages I found that `kernel` take all work, and  `read` holds till the data apears in buffer. When It appears it return to a user.  If end of file appers `read` return will be `0` - and it's time to finish.

Comment: That is how buffers and files work. C is also often equates 1 to 1 or like 1 to 3 to assembly instructions. Its far from abstract. A file is abstract. A network socket is abstract. C makes it possible to code in one language and port it to different machines (which all have different architectures). As long as a compiler is supported.

Comment: If you want abstraction. Use Java or C#. They are pretty nice.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/194290/discussion-between-dmitry-dmitriev-and-bailey-kocin).

Comment: *Question Do EOF appears in buf?* EOF is a condition, not data, so no.

Comment: @Shawn and where do this value appears when `read` system call works? @Baily Kocin told me `EOF will be returned from the read function` and now I'm google about `EOF`.  I know it's a constant depending on `OS`. So `EOF` is not a trailing zero in a string - right?

Comment: `read()` will return 0 to indicate EOF when there's nothing more to be read (Or if the length argument is 0).

Comment: @Shawn `EOF` may be data in case of `getc`.  And this data used as condition. But what I found now, `EOF` dose not evolved in thins that `read` writes in `buf`

Comment: `read()` does not return the `EOF` value that stdio functions like `getc()` use to indicate end of file or error. That one's usually (Always?) -1. When `read()` returns a negative value, it indicates an error, with the exact error in the `errno` variable.

Comment: @Shawn, thank you. I got it and add **UPD2** to the question.

Comment: Read https://latedev.wordpress.com/2012/12/04/all-about-eof/ for lots of details about end of file and what it means.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's deal first with your original question.  Note that `man 7 pipe` should give some useful information on this.

Say we have the standard input redirected to the input side of a descriptor created by a `pipe` call, as in:

```
pipe(p);
// ... fork a child to write to the output side of the pipe ...
dup2(p[0], 0);  // redirect standard input to input side
```

and we call:

```
bytes = read(0, buf, 100);
```

First, note that this behaves no differently than simply reading directly from `p[0]`, so we could have just done:

```
pipe(p);
// fork child
bytes = read(p[0], buf, 100);
```

Then, there are essentially three cases:

1. If there are bytes in the pipe (i.e., at least one byte has been written but not yet read), then the read call will return immediately, and it will return all bytes available up to a maximum of 100 bytes.  The return value will be the number of bytes read, and it will always be a positive number between 1 and 100.
2. If the pipe is empty (no bytes) and the output side has been closed, the buffer won't be touched, and the call will return immediately with return value of 0.
3. Otherwise, the read call will block until something is written to the pipe or the output side is closed, and then the read call will return immediately using the rules in cases 1 and 2.

So, if a `read()` call returns 0, that means the end-of-file was reached, and no more bytes are expected.  Waiting for additional data happens automatically, and after the wait, you'll either get data (positive return value) or an end-of-file signal (zero return value).  In the special case that another process writes some bytes and then immediately closes (the output side of) the pipe, the next `read()` call will return a positive value up to the specified `count`.  Subsequent `read()` calls will continue to return positive values as long as there's more data to read.  When the data are exhausted, the `read()` call will return 0 (since the pipe is closed).

On Linux, the above is always true for pipes and any positive `count`.  There can be differences for things *other* than pipes.  Also, if the `count` is 0, the `read()` call will always return immediately with return value 0.  Note that, if you are trying to write code that runs on platforms other than Linux, you may have to be more careful.  An implementation is allowed to return a non-zero number of bytes less than the number requested, even if more bytes are available in the pipe -- this might mean that there's an implementation-defined limit (so you never get more than 4096 bytes, no matter how many you request, for example) or that this implementation-defined limit changes from call to call (so if you request bytes over a page boundary in a kernel buffer, you only get the end of the page or something).  On Linux, there's no limit -- the read call will always return everything available up to `count`, no matter how big `count` is.

Anyway, the idea is that something like the following code should reliably read all bytes from a pipe until the output side is closed, even on platforms other than Linux:

```
#define _GNU_SOURCE 1
#include <errno.h>
#include <unistd.h>

/* ... */

    while ((count = TEMP_FAILURE_RETRY(read(fd, buffer, sizeof(buffer)))) > 0) {
        // process "count" bytes in "buffer"
    }
    if (count == -1) {
        // handle error
    }
    // otherwise, end of data reached
```

If the pipe is never closed ("endless" or "continuous" stream), the `while` loop will run forever because `read` will block until it can return a non-zero byte count.

Note that the pipe can also be put into a non-blocking mode which changes the behavior substantially, but the above is the default blocking mode behavior.

With respect to your **UPD** questions:

Yes, `read` holds the program execution until data is available, but **NO**, it doesn't necessarily wait for `count` bytes.  It will wait for a least one non-empty `write` to the pipe, and that will wake the process; when the process gets a chance to run, it will return whatever's available *up to* but not necessarily equal to `count` bytes.  Usually, this means that if another process writes 5 bytes, a blocked `read(fd, buffer, 100)` call will return 5 and execution will continue.  Yes, if `read` returns `0`, it's a signal that there's no more data to be read and the write side of the pipe has been closed (so no more data will ever be available).  **No**, an `EOF` value does not appear in the buffer.  Only bytes read will appear there, and the buffer won't be touched when `read()` returns 0, so it'll contain whatever was there before the `read()` call.

With respect to your **UPD2** comment:

Yes, on Linux, EOF is a constant equal to the integer `-1`.  (Technically, according to the C99 standard, it is an integer constant equal to a negative value; maybe someone knows of a platform where it's something other than `-1`.)  This constant is not used by the `read()` interface, and it is certainly not written into the buffer.  While `read()` returns -1 in case of error, it would be considered bad practice to compare the return value from `read()` with EOF instead of -1.  As you note, the EOF value is really only used for C library functions like `getc()` and `getchar()` to distinguish the end of file from a successfully read character.

Comment: Thank you for amazing answer. Things become a lot more clear while some question about `pipe` appears. For me before this answer `pipe` was a command in `shell` that manipulates with `STDOUT`/`STDIN` of process it's run. But here a `pipe` described in context of `C` source code. And it's a bit confusing.  I read `man` to solve this confusion.